# Create a clickable image map on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, imagemap

I wanted to create a clickable map for the United States, when user select a state it will be highlighted and display another detailed view.Like the following web application.

http://www.usflashmap.com/samples/real-estate-map/index_ext.html

I would appreciate any suggestion on how this can be achieved on a native iPhone application.

Thanks in advance,
Sarah

Answer (score 0):

Have a look see here:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/27988-hidden-buttons.html

It's a step in the right direction, I'd too be interested in an example doing it via code.

Answer (score -1):

There's a new app that you can do this with for free.  It makes a customizable US map  http://createaclickablemap.com/

Comment: This app generates flash maps. Flash maps won't run on iPhone.